# Export different sized tables to same excel tab in SAS

Tags: excel, export, append, sas

I have two tables A and B that have a different number of columns, with absolutely no match between the columns names but one differentiator (let's call it ID).

I'm programming a macro in SAS, so that it outputs an excel file such as:
each sheet within the excel is corresponding to an ID.
within each sheet, I have:

```
content of table A
empty line
content of table B
```

The problem is that I can't append rows of data in SAS because columns are non matching.
Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DDE for that - Dynamic Data Exchange Protocol. Basically what it does is simulating user's commands and clicks on various menus and buttons in Excel (and also in Word and some other applications) - or, more exactly, issues commands on now obsolete Macro Language  for Excel  ver. 4 (X4ML).
So, using DDE, you can in SAS program launch Excel, open or create workbook, create tabs (spreadsheets), put your data into specified cells range, format any single cell or range etc.
Here's a good intro into this topic:
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p011-26.pdf